# Should I stop my android service if I will start it again after a short time?

Tags: android, performance, android-service, battery

I have an application that periodically sends data to a server. I want to know what is the best practice for battery usage.

Should I stop the service after sending my data (call `stopSelf()`) or wait until next time I call `startService()` without stopping the service, so methods like `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` won't be called again.

time interval between service calls is like 1 min approx.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with stopping the service and restarting it when needed. If this is an IntentService after all the tasks have been completed it will stop itself without having to call .stopSelf()

Answer (score 3):

The best practise here is to use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) for this kind of work. It is already optimized for battery usage, can batch jobs and have a lot of other optimizations.

Here is an example:

```
ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(context, YourDataSyncService.class);
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPeriodic(60000) //1 min
            .build();

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int result = scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    if (result == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled successfully!");
```

In this case you don't need to leave your service running.

If your API level is < 21, then please check [FireBase job dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)

Also if your service should only sync data between your app and the server - you can check [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html), which was designed especially for this.